# Mysqli->fetch_row issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've never used the new mysqli class in php as the old mysql interface was always good enough however I'm trying to update some old code to use mysqli and things are not going so well and I'm getting the following error:

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object in  [location of file]
```

However I know the query is good because I can echo it and use it directly on the db to give me good results. I have a feeling I'm using the "fetch_row() incorrectly.

Can someone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

```
/// class setup stuff
public function query($query,$sanitize=TRUE)
    {       
        if($sanitize!==FALSE)
        {
            $query=$this->mysqli->escape_string($query);
        }
        echo $query;
        $this->mysqli->query($query);
        echo $this->mysqli->error;
        //$this->mysqli->free();
    }    
public function select($table,$what,$where,$orderby=FALSE,$order=FALSE,$limits=FALSE,$sanitize=TRUE) //this is really simple and very limited
        {
            //process the select query and send to query method
            $query = "SELECT $what FROM $table WHERE ";
            $i = 0;
            foreach($where as $key => $value)
            {
                $key    = $sanitize?$this->mysqli->escape_string($key):$key;
                $value  = $sanitize?$this->mysqli->escape_string($value):$value;
                $query  .= "$key='$value' ";
                $i++;
                if($i<count($where))
                {
                    $query .= "AND ";
                }
            }
            // check the max rowcount 
            $this->query($query,FALSE);
            $result = $this->mysqli->use_result(); //<--this is the issue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @scones' suggestion I tested the connection after initializing it and found that the issues was the 'use_result' and the fact that I hadnt returned the result in the query function. Here's the working version notice `$result = $this->query($query,FALSE);`

```
public function query($query,$sanitize=TRUE)
{       
    if($sanitize!==FALSE)
    {
        $query=$this->mysqli->escape_string($query);
    }
    echo $query;
    if($this->mysqli->error)
    {
        echo $this->mysqli->error;
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->mysqli->query($query); //<-- needed this
    }
    //$this->mysqli->free();
}

public function select($table,$what,$where,$orderby=FALSE,$order=FALSE,$limits=FALSE,$sanitize=TRUE) //this is really simple and very limited
{
    //process the select query and send to query method
    $query = "SELECT $what FROM $table WHERE ";
    $i = 0;
    foreach($where as $key => $value)
    {
        $key    = $sanitize?$this->mysqli->escape_string($key):$key;
        $value  = $sanitize?$this->mysqli->escape_string($value):$value;
        $query  .= "$key='$value' ";
        $i++;
        if($i<count($where))
        {
            $query .= "AND ";
        }
    }
    $result = $this->query($query,FALSE);  //<-- works now
```

Answer (score 2):

$this->mysqli is not initialized

Comment: I use this in my __construct function: $this->mysqli  = new mysqli($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass,$this->name,$this->port);
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $this->mysqli->error );
       exit();
   }

Comment: you might want to test in the line after new, if it was successful

Comment: I could dump the whole class in the question but it might be a bit tedious for people?

Comment: well, somehow after looking at your code again: those two functions do not use `fetch_row()`. your error is elsewhere

Comment: I agree with scones that the error is somewhere else. May be you can use PHP's debug_print_backtrace() to find what is called before the script reaches fetch_row();

Comment: ahh, I've cracked it... bad code. I'll write my own answer and upvote you both ;-)